# trouble understanding d3 tree node transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am modifying a open source angular library, [angular-d3-tree](https://github.com/jgpATs2w/angular-d3-tree).  I am modifying because I want to make my nodes render as rectangles.  I got the rectangle part worked out but I cannot figure out how to keep the rectangles from over lapping:

[image]

I have noticed these `transform` attributes getting add to nodes like this:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "   translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        //return 'translate(' + source.y + ',' + (source.x + 150) + ')';
        // return 'translate(' + source.y + ',' + (source.x + 150) + ')';
        // return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + (source.x0 + 150) + ")";
    });
    .
    .
    .

var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);


nodeUpdate.transition()
  .duration(this.duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
      console.log('RBC trans d is:');
      console.log(d);
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x  + ")";
      // return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x  + ")";
      // return "translate(" + d.y + "," + (d.x + 150)  + ")";
   });
```

Anytime I make a change to the transform attributes either nothing changes or I just make things worse.  Could some please explain to me how I can keep my rectangles from overlapping?  I am just grasping at straws here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a static modification of the transform will only shift every node in one direction or the other. However, we can use d3.tree to avoid overlap out of the box, assuming we know the size of the rectangles (or max size).

D3.tree offers two methods for sizing:

1. `tree.size([width,height])`, this will take your tree and place its nodes within a box of the provided dimensions. It makes no assumptions about the size of each node: the more nodes and/or the larger the nodes are, the more likely there is overlap. With this method the tree size is specified and nodes are positioned accordingly.
2. `tree.nodeSize([width,height])`, this takes a tree and places nodes so that they are spaced in a manner that gives each node the specified size. The overall size of the tree is dictated by the structure of the tree and the spacing of the nodes. With this method the node spacing is specified and the tree is sized accordingly.

*With the second approach the root node is placed at [0,0], this requires a transform to be applied on all nodes to place them properly. The first approach does not require this  since the dimension of the plot area is known and the root is placed properly.

*width and height are in this order for a vertical tree, horizontal trees will be reversed*.

If we know the size of the rectangles, we can set nodeSize to those dimensions, plus some additional margin to allow the connecting paths to be seen. For example, adopting [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/efa049e8015024669f56ec634e6a7394), we can convert it to use rectangular nodes by:

- specifying a node size
- appending rectangles rather than circles
- reposition the text slightly
- and change the translate on the parent g so [0,0] is half way down the page on the left (where our root node will appear):

```js
var data = { "name": "Parent", "children": [ 
 { "name": "Child A", "children": [ { "name": "Grandchild" } ] }, 
 { "name": "Child B", } 
 ] };

var width = 800;
var height = 200;

margin = {left: 100, top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 50}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
   
var g = svg.append("g").attr('transform','translate('+ margin.left +','+ (height/2) +')');

var root = d3.hierarchy(data);
   
var tree = d3.tree()
    .nodeSize([50,100]); // because we are using a horizontal tree this is [height,width] of each node

 var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(tree(root).links())
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
          .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
          .y(function(d) { return d.x; }));

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 80)
   .attr("height", 40)
   .attr("x", -40) // half of width
   .attr("y", -20) // half of height
   .attr("rx",5)
   .attr("ry",5)
   .attr("fill","steelblue")
   
  node.append("text")
     .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
  .attr('y',5)
  .attr('text-anchor','middle');
```

```css
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

[Here's](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/b189ab7e51ae50ac9c91feaf625693d5) a full size version.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your help.  I was wondering if you could help me with another question I have about links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201422/how-do-i-control-the-links-in-my-d3-tree again thanks!