# How do I control the links in my D3 tree?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am modifying an open source library, [angular-d3-tree](https://github.com/jgpATs2w/angular-d3-tree)
I am having hard time getting the links to my nodes in my D3 tree.  Here is what my tree looks like:

[image]

I want my links to start at the center of the back of rectangles not the top left of the rectangle.  I think that is is controlled from this method defined in angular-d3-tree:

```
  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  diagonalCurvedPath(s, d) {
    console.log('diagonalCurvedPath() called s and d are:');
    console.log(s);
    console.log(d);
    const path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }
```

`diagonalCurvedPath` gets used in this routine:

```
  setLinks( source: any, treeData: any){
    let links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);
    var link = this.svg.selectAll('path.link')
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('d', (d)=>{
          var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
          return this.diagonalCurvedPath(o, o)
        });

    var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

    linkUpdate.transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr('d', (d)=>{return this.diagonalCurvedPath(d, d.parent)});

    var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr('d', (d) => {
          var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
          return this.diagonalCurvedPath(o, o)
        })
        .remove();
  }
```

I have tried to make changes to `diagonalCurvedPath` with disastrous results.  I don't understand what ...

```
const path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
        C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
          ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
          ${d.y} ${d.x}`
```

... means. What's `M` and what the heck is `C`?  Please help as I am just grasping at straws and not getting anywhere :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok I figured it out. by reading this: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js
 I am now using this code to set `path`.

```
/*
M ( m ) x, y    moveto

Move the pen to a new location. No line is drawn. All path data must begin with a 'moveto' command.

Cubic Bezier Curve Commands
     C ( c )    x1 y1 x2 y2 x y

     Draw a cubic Bézier curve from the current point to the point (x,y)
     using (x1,y1) as the control point at the beginning of the curve and
     (x2,y2) as the control point at the end of the curve.
 */
const path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x + this.rect_height/2}
              C ${(s.y + d.y + this.rect_width) / 2}  ${s.x + this.rect_height/2}
                ${(s.y + d.y + this.rect_width) / 2}  ${d.x + this.rect_height/2}
                ${d.y + this.rect_width} ${d.x + this.rect_height/2}`
```

Where rect_width and rect_height are the width and height of the rectangle nodes I am draw the curves between.